# nginx rewrite if requst_uri contains some numbers

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm having a little problem with some rewrite rules for a website.

My permalinks are now something like domain.com/ID/permalink-ID.html

The old structure of permalinks was domain.com/permalink-ID.html

That ID is an integer number.

How can i create a rewrite rule for nginx so that

domain.com/permalink-ID.html redirects to domain.com/ID/permalink-ID.html

I can do that manually... but there are about 25k posts like that.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Test this one out:

```
rewrite ^/?permalink-(\d+).html http://domain.com/$1/permalink-$1.html permanent;
```

Answer (score 0):

Because the number and the permalink is dynamic, here the proposed solution

```
    location ~* ^/(((?!/).)+)-(\d+)\.html$ {
        return 301 $scheme://$host/$3/$1-$3.html;
    }
```

For redirect, you can use return instead rewrite. For explanation the regex scheme, please refer [this site](http://regex101.com/r/nF0pS4/2).